# What is the error of this jsx expression?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Here I am trying to do some sort of conditional rendering ,So I need to have a different output based on the state attribute dailyData value but why can't I use if statement like this ?

**compile time error  called Parsing error: Unexpected token.**

```
render(){
     let lineChart = (
             if(!this.state.dailyData){
                 <h1>Loading</h1>
             }
             else{
                  <h1>Output</h1>
              }
        );
     return(<div className={container}>
               {lineChart}  
            </div>
           );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it is not a JSX problem but JS syntax error. `if` is a statement not an expression so you can't assign it to a variable `lineChart`.

So instead:

```js
render(){
    let lineChart;

    if (!this.state.dailyData) {
       lineChart = <h1>Loading</h1>;
    } else {
       lineChart = <h1>Output</h1>;
    }

    return(<div className={container}>
        {lineChart}  
    <div>);
}
```

[Here](https://2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html) is the difference between statements and expressions

Answer (score 2):

> Keep it simple:

```
renderLineChart = () => {
  return !this.state.dailyData ? <h1>Loading</h1> : <h1>Output</h1>;
}

render(){
  return(<div className={container}>
           {this.renderLineChart()}  
         </div>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `if/else` as an expression. Use [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) instead.

```
let lineChart = !this.state.dailyData ? (<h1>Loading</h1>) : (<h1>Output</h1>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use ternary operator here.

```
let lineChart = !this.state.dailyData ? <h1>Loading</h1> : <h1>Output</h1>
```

Also your enclosing div tag should be `</div>` instead of `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is good, but the way you wrote it is not correct and contains syntax error. Here are the two ways of how you can achieve what you want.

1st

```
render() {
  let lineChart = null;

  if (!this.state.dailyData) {
    lineChart = <h1>Loading</h1>;
  } else {
    lineChart = <h1>Output</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <div className={container}>
      {lineChart}  
    <div>
  );
}
```

2nd

```
render() {
  let lineChart = !this.state.dailyData 
    ? <h1>Loading</h1>
    : <h1>Output</h1>

  return (
    <div className={container}>
      {lineChart}  
    <div>
  );
}
```